# Do the Hong Kong metro lines have numbers?

Tags: public-transport, maps, hong-kong

Before I travelled to Hong Kong, I looked at the [MTR Map](http://www.mtr.com.hk/eng/getting_around/system_map.html), which described all the lines by colour and by name, but not by number. Generally, the signs up around the MTR did the same.

However, a few times, and especially when changing trains, I spotted signs with name + colour + number. This would've been easier for me, as in a jetlagged state remembering "I want the line that starts with a T" turned out to not be nearly so unique as planned...

Are there actually numbers for lines, or do the numbers mean something else? I didn't get a chance to take a photo, but below is a cc-by photo from Flickr which shows the kind of sign I spotted:

[image: MTR sign from Nasa Dulo ng Dila from www.flickr.com/photos/24536908@N00/83264048]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are platform numbers. The colour indicates the line but the number is specific to the station. ([Online confirmation](http://invisibledesigns.org/mtr-colour-coding-2/))

You can note the platform numbers (I think trains of different lines always leave from different platforms in Hong Kong, ), but they vary from station to station.

Comment: As a HongKonger, I believe the platform numbers are used for directing passengers to the *suitable* platform. E.g. [East Rail Line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Rail) train could stop at "Lok Ma Chau" or "Lo Wu" or even "Tai Po Market". A broadcasting message is issued and related information is displayed on the panel in the station. It is most commonly used in the Terminal station.